# Stop Browser at any spot

Tags: browser

I have checked many questions and answers regarding how to stop any browser at any time, but I have not found a solution to my problem.

I have a logout button in my application, and when I press it, it adds some classes to an `<a>` tag. Is there any key/shortcut to stop the Mozilla/Chrome (any browser) to perform the actions or stay the same page?

Comment: @jmort253: actually Is their any way to capture/show/stop the browser screen when event was shoot and page is just turned to antoher?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I believe you're looking for is a debugger with **breakpoints**.  Breakpoints allow you to mark certain sections of your code as points where you want the execution of that code to temporarily pause its state until a point in which you are ready to proceed to the next breakpoint.

Modern browsers, such as Google Chrome (or any other WebKit browser like Safari) or Mozilla Firefox with the Firebug Firefox extension have this capability.

### **Chrome (WebKit Browsers):**

You can set breakpoints in your JavaScript in the "Scripts" tab of Chrome (and most WebKit browsers):

From [Chrome Developer Tools: Script Breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints):

> - Open the Developer Tools by hitting the Control-Shift-I shortcut
> - Open Scripts panel and select "script.js" from scripts drop-down
> - Set breakpoint on line 19 by clicking the line gutter (you can use the Control-G shortcut to reveal a line in a large file)
> - Move your mouse over this page
> - You should stop on the breakpoint
> - Hover over the source code to inspect local and global variables, function arguments etc.
> - Delete the breakpoint by clicking the blue tag breakpoint indicator
> - Click the Continue  button or hit F8 in Developer Tools window to resume

[image: Set Breakpoint in Chrome]

### **Firefox with Firebug:**

There are [countless demonstrations of Firebug Breakpoints](http://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html) and other debugger functionality located on this page.

The functionality is very similar to that of the Developer Tools in  WebKit browsers.

[image]

### **Internet Explorer:**

Internet Explorer also has built in Developer Tools, which among many other features gives users the ability to set breakpoints and stop execution of the scripts. While the Chrome Debugger is sufficient in many cases, there are certain bugs and cross-browser issues that tend to affect Internet Explorer more so than other browsers.

Thus, the [Setting Breakpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625(v=vs.85).aspx#_break) section of the "Debugging Script with the Developer Tools" page will be most helpful when attempting to resolve issues that only affect Internet Explorer.

[image]

Comment: @jmort253: +1 for awesome answer, really I was needed this but currently forgot about :)